# Did Voldemort Kill Anyone By Means Other Than Avada Kedavra? (Aside from ...)

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

> **... Snape? Did Voldemort ever *directly* kill anyone by any means other than Avada Kedavra besides directing Nagini to kill Snape?**

I considered Regulus Black as a candidate, but Voldemort did not directly kill Regulus with conscious intent. Regulus discovered the existence of the Horcrux cave and technically allowed himself to be drowned by the Inferi in the lake there in order to swap out the real Horcrux for the fake one.

Is there anyone else besides Snape?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were several murders that may borderline qualify:

- Hepizba Smith (poisoned by either Voldemort himself, or Winky on his Imperius)
- Merope Riddle (by being born)
- Peter Pettigrew (killed by Voldemort-provided metal hand).
- Quirrell (borderline qualifies)

Comment: Also, 2 Unicorns may count in PS.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  The Dark Lord has killed Moaning Myrtle using the stare of a Basilisk.  This certainly counts as a killing by the Dark Lord, for he has made a Horcrux from it.

Comment: If Slytherincess isn't counting Voldemort directing Nagini to kill Snape, I'm not sure Tom Riddle ordering the basilisk from the Chamber of Secrets to kill Moaning Myrtle (if he even did - I think there's an argument that she was just in the wrong place at the wrong time) would count either. Also, I'm not aware of Voldemort/Tom Riddle making a horcrux as a result of that death.

Comment: Ah, looks like I misunderstood the question somewhat, and she's not discounting Snape. The rest of my points still stand, though - I don't think Tom Riddle ordered the basilisk to kill Moaning Myrtle, she simply happened to be there (and therefore suffer its gaze) when the basilisk was exiting the Chamber of Secrets - and there's no mention or evidence that I recall/am aware of that he made a horcrux as a result.

Comment: @b_jonas: He made a horcrux? Of *Myrtle*? ***The*** **Moarning *Myrtle***? Well, Riddle disappoints me then.

Comment: @Voldemort So sad to be disappointed in yourself...